# Add custom application media controls in unity panel volume control

Tags: unity, rhythmbox, panel, volume-control, widgets

I wrote a small bash application that allows me to control the music streamed from my phone to my PC via bluetooth, and I would like to know how to add a Rhythmbox like widget in Unity panel's volume control for my application.

[image: This is the Rhythmbox widget I'm referring to]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a MPRIS DBUS interface same as any other player.

[MPRIS D-Bus Interface Specification](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/index.html)

Some thing else related to the sound indicator, your app should have an `.desktop` to be identified by the indicator.